# How to run Browser application bundle generation once when running "ng test --watch=false && ng build --configuration production"?

Tags: angular, continuous-integration, angular-test

For an angular application, on our build pipelines we're running this command: "ng test --watch=false && ng build --configuration production". And each command (ng test & ng build) takes approximately 2 minutes on the server due to "Generating browser application bundles". Which at the end slows down the CI and causes at least 4 minutes delay that could be only 2 if "Generating browser application bundles" didn't run twice for each command.

Does anyone have an idea why that is and if there's a way to use the same browser application bundles and save some time?

*1st one is for test 2nd one is for build:
*[image: 1st one is for test 2nd one is for build]

Tried running build first and test, that also didn't help